# What kind of receptacle to buy for a Tappan Stove-top (electric)?

Tags: stove

I was just wondering what kind of receptacle I would need for a Tappan stove. Recently one of them burned out and I would like to replace it. It's the part that the heating coil plugs into with the hot neutral wires on it.

It's confusing as to what one I need when the pictures are all low resolution and claim broad compatibility with a brand name.

Comment: What exactly is this question about?

Comment: stove-top replacement "receptacle" for old and somewhat obscure brand Tappan (after having bought the wrong ones and since this is wrong everywhere on the internet too)

Comment: I see. Well, we do like when people provide their own answers, but can you please clarify what the problem is that requires this solution? The question statement is really unclear (and the solution seems to be more of a product recommendation than anything, so maybe make it a bit more general).

Comment: @HariGanti is that clearer?

Comment: You might want to also attach pictures of the receptacle you are referring to. It *seems* like you're talking about the contacts for a burner coil, but when i saw "receptacle," I thought it had some crazy requirement like a NEMA 6-30R or a NEMA 5-50R, etc.

Comment: I am talking about the contacts for the burner coil, I put the pictures at the bottom in the answer.

Comment: To me, those pictures really don't indicate anything. In-context pictures are best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two kinds of generic plugs, one of them has small circles, the constitutes a more traditional plug **you don't want this**

[image: don't buy]

The other one has friction slots. Tappan uses the friction slots.

[image: buy this]

For my specific Tappan stove I used [RR117 from Supco](http://www.supco.com/web/supco_live/products/RR117.html) (pictured above).

It was marketed on eBay as

> Frigidaire Kenmore Gibson Tappan Stove Burner Terminal Receptacle Kit 5301167733

The bag says it replaces 5303935058, 330031, 868464, 709T034S01, WB17X210, 0089336, W10116799

If you need wire, for my job I paid $10 and got some nice stuff.

- [Copper Wire, 14 GA, AWG, GAUGE .116. High Heat, Resist Abrasions. For Truck, Motorcycle, RV. General Purpose. (25 FOOT COIL)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H9HY2VE)